# How to share an AI Platform JupyterLab among multiple users?

Tags: gcp-ai-platform-notebook

This is my understanding that anyone with project editor permissions can access the AI Platform Jupyter notebooks, which is great but not very practical since this could cause several issues. I would like to use this environment as an "always-on" machine with GPU enabled and allow different people in my team to access it. Right now everyone is logged in as the default "jupyter" user when logging in with **OPEN JUPYTERLAB** button. Is there a way to log in with different credentials?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would you mind describing your setup and why you'd like everyone to use the same notebook?  E.g. Are you a business, a group of freinds, etc? And are you sharing to save on cost or because you're trying to have multiple people edit the same set of files?   Generally, it's best if everyone uses their own notebook and shares code via Git

Comment: This is an always-on GPU machine for my research group. Cost-saving is the main incentive. Code is being already shared via git. I am looking for a simple way to get separate spaces for different users, say different linux usernames, etc. Similar way that a user gets authenticated to a GCP linux instance when they SSH into it. In that case, not everyone has the same username. In AI Platform anyone on the project can log in to a notebook instance and operate as user "jupyter".

Answer (score 0):

Today it's not possible to use different credentials with the OPEN JUPYTERLAB button.

However, you have SSH access to the underlying VM.  You could have each person SSH into the VM with port forwarding.  Then everyone would be directly using JupyterLab without the Proxy intermediary.

It's a little less user friendly, but will get you distinct users

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your solution but still get logged in as "jupyter" user. I did

`gcloud compute ssh "INSTANCE-NAME" -- -L 8080:localhost:8080`

But gave me what the open jupyterlab button does. Did I miss anything?